# Ubuntu + Windows 8 -> Dell 14z 5423 AHCI / ISRT

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ssd, gpt, ahci

I just bought a Dell 14z 5423, which uses UEFI/GPT and Intel Smart Response on the Windows 8.

I have been researching and studying how to use it as Dual boot.

Thanks to this forum I was able to install ubuntu 13.04 alongside with windows 8, disabling IRST and changing Sata Mode to AHCI.

Although I haven't was able to enable the ISRT yet, I, letting Sata Mode to ACHI, was able to boot both windows 8 and ubuntu.

Today I started it and ubuntu does not boot anymore. Nothing has changed. I could say that i installed some updates, by I had tested and it was ok.

Why it's been so troubly to have ubuntu + windows 8?

What do I have to do to have my ubuntu booting again?

What do I have to do to install ubuntu drivers for RAID (Intel Smart Response), and then how shall I use the accelerate mode in both discs?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You said "Nothing has changed. I could say that i installed some updates, by I had tested and it was ok." Those two sentences directly contradict each other, and the second is unclear -- in which OS did you install updates, and what type of updates were they? If I had to guess, I'd say that you installed Windows updates, and as a result, the Windows boot loader was re-registered as the primary boot loader for the computer.

If I'm right, this is relatively easily fixed within Windows:

1. Launch an *Administrator* Command Prompt window. (You *must* have administrative privileges for this to work.)
2. Type `mountvol S: /S`
3. Look over the `S:` volume. There should be an `EFI` directory that contains various subdirectories, including `EFI\ubuntu`, which should have one or more files with names that end in `.efi`. Take note of what they are.
4. Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. Note, however, that you may need to change the filename. If Secure Boot is disabled, change `shimx64.efi` to `grubx64.efi`; and if you've installed another boot manager (such as rEFInd or gummiboot), you should change the entire pathname to refer to it. Whatever you use as a filename, be sure that it exists on `S:`.

There are other ways to deal with this problem, too, such as running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a Linux live CD or installing [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) However you handle the problem, it's possible it will recur, so you should be prepared to repair the boot system in the future.

Comment: The updates I meant was on ubuntu 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'. It was working normally, the last thing I've done was boot on windows yesterday. Today, it was still running windows, and when I rebooted, ubuntu did not show up, it stuck on 'Loading initial ramdisk'.

Comment: I quite solved it yesterday changing Sata Mode to ACHI, but it is not working anymore.
About the boot-repair, it was the way I found to display grub with ubuntu and windows, which was not showing up after ubuntu install

Comment: Do you have multiple Ubuntu options in your GRUB menu? If so, try loading an earlier kernel. It's possible that you've upgraded to a more recent kernel and the new one is buggy. If you can load an older kernel but not a newer one, then I recommend you [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) One other suggestion: Re-run Boot Repair. It's conceivable that it did some tweaking to kernel options that haven't been applied to a new kernel, so running it again may help.

Comment: I did boot-repair couple times and yes, I tried all the kernels avaiable there. I can't figure out why this happened, yesterday I was able to boot it on AHCI sata mode, I'd start installing my applications today.

Comment: I realized that if I enter setup, and just save it, ubuntu boots. But everytime I reboot I have to do it. It's very weird to me..

Comment: Please revise your question to specify what happens when you attempt to boot but it fails. For instance, does GRUB complain that it can't find a file? Does the system just hang with no output? Does the system show an Ubuntu logo and then hang? Also, please try tryping `e` at the GRUB menu and remove the `quiet` option from the kernel option list. This will cause a more verbose boot, which may provide more information -- it may give you an error message or hang at a point that gives a clue about what's wrong.

Comment: if I don't enter setup and save it, ubuntu even in recovery mode stucks on 'initramfs'. About the logo, it does not show any logo, I realized that if I disable 'Load OPROM', e.g. Legacy BIOS, it shows the logo, but hangs with the message 'ERROR Cannot initialize the agpgart module' and enter in command mode (which is better than just don't boot), about this I tried to install extra Radeon drivers trought jockey, but with no success. About entering in grub and pressing 'e', I didn't see any changes when I try to edit it..

Comment: I tried 13.10 but I can't even boot the system after install.. I'm really getting annoyed with this situation, and I can't realize if this is my laptop's problem or ubuntu bug..

Comment: Would you guys think if I erase everything and try ubuntu first than windows it would work?

Comment: My advice is to return the computer and buy another one. It's probably possible to fix your problems, but it will take a lot more back-and-forth to fix it, or a lot of study of EFI boot issues on your part.